# Doubts with some Vim commands and macros (The missing semester of your CS Education, parse XML to JSON with Vim macros)

Tags: json, xml, vim

I'm trying this exercise from [*The missing semester of your CS Education, Lecture 3: Editors (Vim)*](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2020/editors/):

8. (Advanced) Convert XML to JSON ([example file](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2020/files/example-data.xml)) using Vim macros. Try to do this on your own, but you can look at the macros section above if you get stuck.

They give this solution:

1. `Gdd, ggdd` delete first and last lines
2. Macro to format a single element (register `e`)

   - Go to line with `<name>`
   - `qe^r"f>s": "<ESC>f<C"<ESC>q`
3. Macro to format a person (register `p`)

   - Go to line with `<person>`
   - `qpS{<ESC>j@eA,<ESC>j@ejS},<ESC>q`
4. Macro to format a person and go to the next person (register `q`)

   - Go to line with `<person>`
   - `qq@pjq`
5. Execute macro until end of file

   - `999@q`
6. Manually remove last `,` and add `[` and `]` delimiters

I don't understand commands like:

- `<C`
- `^r"f>s":`
- `S{<ESC>j@eA,<ESC>j@ejS}`

Among others, could someone do a breakdown of the solution in order to understand the commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `<C`

  This one is meaningless because you split the command at the wrong place. The correct place is between `f<` and `C"`:

  1. `f<` means "move the cursor to the next `<` on the line", see `:help f`.
  2. `C"` means "cut the rest of the line and insert a `"`", see `:help C`.
- `^r"f>s":`

  1. `^` means "move the cursor to the first printable character of the line", see `:help ^`.
  2. `r"` means "replace the current character with a `"`", see `:help r`.
  3. `f>` means "move the cursor to the next `>` on the fine", see `:help f`.
  4. `s":` is actually `s": "`, meaning "replace the current character with `": "`, see `:help s`.
- `S{<ESC>j@eA,<ESC>j@ejS}`

  1. `S{` means "replace the whole line with a `"` at the correct indentation", see `:help S`.
  2. `<ESC>` is the `Escape` key, see `:help key-notation`.
  3. `j` means "go down one line", see `:help j`.
  4. `@e` means "play back macro stored in register `e`", see `:help @`.
  5. `A,` means "append a `,` at the end of the line", see `:help A`.
  6. `<ESC>`, `j`, `@e`, `j`, and `S}` have already been explained.

All of that is pretty easy to piece out after a while (I rarely need to use Vim itself when answering Vim questions) but it sure is a lot to take in without the proper foundations.

That cryptic example is really a case of giving the reader a quasi-magical fish instead of teaching them how to fish. I am not sure what the people behind those "get rich quick" Vim articles and courses think they are achieving but questions like this one should make them pause a little.

The subject matter is much too complex to be covered in one lecture or in a short webpage so I would suggest you learn Vim properly instead of consuming context-free content like this.

1. If you haven't already, do `$ vimtutor` as many times as needed to get the basics right.
2. As instructed at the end of vimtutor, level up to the user manual `:help user-manual`. It's a hands-on tutorial that will guide you progressively through *every* feature, from basic to advanced. Go at your own pace and, most importantly, experiment along the way.
3. Keep an eye on anti-patterns and inefficient actions, find improvements, practice. Rinse. Repeat.

Comment: Since I read this comment first time at the begining of August I am reading de user manual and watching TheFrugalComputerGuy tutorials. I am now more familiar with macros and use them daily, now learning a bit better folding options, splits and tabs. Now I miss Vim when I use other editors.